# Edited Vector Drawable not showing in the app

Tags: android, svg, vector-graphics, inkscape

I've taken out [this icon](https://materialdesignicons.com/icon/check-all) SVG and I've edited it in Inkscape to make the double tick icon look like the WhatsApp one.

So, later in Android Studio I put the original vector drawable icon:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path android:fillColor="#000" android:pathData="M0.41,13.41L6,19L7.41,17.58L1.83,12M22.24,5.58L11.66,16.17L7.5,12L6.07,13.41L11.66,19L23.66,7M18,7L16.59,5.58L10.24,11.93L11.66,13.34L18,7Z" />
</vector>
```

And then I've replaced the pathData with the SVG path edited in Inkscape:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#000"
        android:pathData="M 0.41,13.41 6,19 7.41,17.58 1.83,12 M 22.24,5.58 11.66,16.2 11,15.5 9.5,17 11.66,19 23.66,7 M 18,7 16.5,5.5 4.5, 17.5 6,19 Z"/>
</vector>
```

I can see the new icon in Android Studio preview, but when I run the app it **doesn't show**. Normal icons does show normally, but this one doesn't.

It's a weird behavior that I cannot understand, I'm pretty new into vector graphics.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer by myself. Looking at the original icon syntax it appears that spaces should be given with an `L` letter.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path android:fillColor="#8A000000" android:pathData="M0.41,13.41L6,19L7.41,17.58L1.83,12M22.24,5.58L11.66,16.2L11,15.5L9.5,17L11.66,19L23.66,7M18,7L16.5,5.5L4.5,17.5L6,19Z"/>
</vector>
```

Now it works. Funny how I didn't know anything about vector drawable, and still found a solution.